# System call to count number of children in a process

Tags: c, process, operating-system, xv6

I've done all the steps to create a system call, and then created a user program and run it:

proc.c

```
int countChildren (int pid) {

    struct proc *p;
    int count = 0;

    acquire(&ptable.lock);

    for(p = ptable.proc; p < &ptable.proc[NPROC]; p++)
      if(p->parent->pid == pid) count++;

    release(&ptable.lock);

    return count;
}
```

sysproc.c

```
int
sys_getchildren(void)
{ 
    int pid;
    argint(0, &pid);
    return countChildren(pid);

}
```

userProgram.c

```
...
#include "types.h"
#include "user.h"

int main (void) {

    int n1 = fork(); 

    int n2 = fork();

    int n3 = fork();

    int n4 = fork(); 

    if (n1 > 0 && n2 > 0 && n3 > 0 && n4 > 0) { 
        printf(1,"parent\n"); 
        printf(1," getchildren = %d \n", getchildren()); 
    } 
    exit();
}
```

But the result is not what I expected, below is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your kernel code is corrected, your problem comes from the user code: 
you create processes but you do not take care of them so they become zombies and could not be counted.

When a process exit and is not waited by its parent, it become a zombie:

a zombie is a process is adopted by the init process (see `exit` definition in file `proc.c`) and cannot be counted in child.

To correct your testing code, make the processes to sleep for some time and to wait their child:

```
#include "types.h"
#include "user.h"

int main (void) {

    int n1 = fork(); 
    int n2 = fork();
    int n3 = fork();
    int n4 = fork(); 

    if (n1 > 0 && n2 > 0 && n3 > 0 && n4 > 0) { 
        printf(1,"parent\n"); 
        printf(1," getchildren = %d \n", getchildren()); 
    } 

    /* wait for all child to terminate */
    while(wait() != -1) { }

    /* give time to parent to reach wait clause */
    sleep(1);

    exit();
}
```

---

Edit: you have a little typo in syscall, instead of `getint` you should get `pid` from `myproc`:

```
int
sys_getchildren(void)
{ 
    int pid;
    pid = myproc()->pid;
    return countChildren(pid);
}
```

or shorter:

```
int
sys_getchildren(void)
{ 
    return countChildren(myproc()->pid);
}
```

Comment: Even when I use the above code, it says that `getchildren = 1` whereas the parent process should have 4 direct children, am I wrong?

Comment: @mahdigh: indeed, the `pid` was not correctly set in syscall. see my update